# How to use "Swipe Menu Jquery Mobile" with jquery 3.1.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

For my PhoneGap project, I try to implement the source code example from: https://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/ (see bottom page)

The probleme is: I should use the latest Jquery version for security reasons.
So, When i replace   `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` by   `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>` there is some errors.

Are there issue ? or do you know other "Swipe Menue" simple example with JQuery Mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jqueryMobile 1.4.5` which is the latest stable version of jqueryMobile is not compatible with the latest `jquery-3.1.0`.`jqueryMobile 1.4.5` is compatible upto `jquery-2.2.4`.So you have to use `jquery-2.2.4` or lower version of `jQuery`.